# Using @Transactional: transaction get commited even if exception thrown

Tags: spring, struts2, mybatis

I m using struts2 - spring 3.2.2 and mybatis.

First of all my requirements are:

Make a transaction management utility in which

1. Transaction must be rolled back if any exception thrown in other statement of current transaction. (The other db operations may be performed through various classes, i.e. not in same class.)

Following the requirements, i ve created simple program.
my applicationContext.xml file:

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
     xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
     xsi:schemaLocation="
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
        <!-- Initialization for data source -->
   <bean id="dataSource" 
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;database=master;integratedSecurity=true;"/>
      <property name="username" value="Jaydeep"/>
      <property name="password" value="Acty#System123"/>
   </bean>

    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

        <property name='mapperLocations' value='classpath*:test/xml/*.xml' />
    </bean>

    <bean class='org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer'>
      <property name='basePackage' value='test.dao' />
    </bean>

    <bean id='sqlSession' class='org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate'>
      <constructor-arg index='0' ref='sqlSessionFactory' />
    </bean>

   <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

   <bean id="serviceProvider"
      class="DataServiceProvider">
      <property name="sqlSession"  ref="sqlSession" />    
   </bean>

    <bean id="updutil" class="MyUpdateUtil">
        <property name="serviceProvider" ref="serviceProvider"></property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

//DataServiceProvider.java

```
import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSession;
import test.dao.DepartmentMapper;
import test.dao.EmployeeMapper;

public class DataServiceProvider {
    private SqlSession sqlSession;
    public DepartmentMapper getDeptMapper() {
        if(sqlSession != null)
            return sqlSession.getMapper(DepartmentMapper.class);
        else
            System.out.println("session null");
        return null;
    }
    public EmployeeMapper getEmpMapper() {
        if(sqlSession != null)
            return sqlSession.getMapper(EmployeeMapper.class);
        else
            System.out.println("session null");
        return null;
    }

    public SqlSession getSqlSession() {
        return sqlSession;
    }

    public void setSqlSession(SqlSession sqlSession) {
        this.sqlSession = sqlSession;
    }
}
```

//Interface: fooService.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import test.model.Department;

@Transactional
public interface fooService {

    public void update(boolean isThrow) throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IOException;

    public void insert(Department dept) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException;

    public void select() throws IOException;
}
```

//Utility class in which all db related operations will be performed
//MyUpdateUtil.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import test.model.Department;
import test.model.Employee;
import test.model.EmployeeExample;

@Transactional
public class MyUpdateUtil implements fooService {

    public void update(boolean isThrow) throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IOException  {
        System.out.println("Updating...................Transaction alive? ..." + StartTransAction.isActive());
        if(isThrow)
            throw new RuntimeException("simulate Error condition") ;
        Employee record = new Employee();
        EmployeeExample example = new EmployeeExample();
        example.createCriteria().andDeptidEqualTo(1L);

        record.setEmpid(1L);
        record.setDeptid(1L);
        record.setEmpname("jaydeep");
        record.setSalary(BigDecimal.valueOf(2000));

        getServiceProvider().getEmpMapper().updateByExampleWithBLOBs(record, example);
    }
    @Transactional
    public void insert(Department dept) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
        System.out.println("Inserting....................Transaction alive? .." + StartTransAction.isActive());
        getServiceProvider().getDeptMapper().insert(dept);
    }

    public void select() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Dept Info");
        List<Department> deptList = getServiceProvider().getDeptMapper().selectByExampleWithBLOBs(null);
        for(Department d : deptList) {
            System.out.println("Dept ID: " + d.getDeptid());
            System.out.println("Dept Name: " + d.getDeptname());
        }
        System.out.println("Emp Info");
        List<Employee> empList = getServiceProvider().getEmpMapper().selectByExampleWithBLOBs(null);
        for(Employee e : empList) {
            System.out.println("Emp ID: " + e.getEmpid());
            System.out.println("Dept ID: " + e.getDeptid());
            System.out.println("Emp Name: " + e.getEmpname());
        }
    }   
    @Autowired(required=true)
    private DataServiceProvider serviceProvider;
    public DataServiceProvider getServiceProvider() {
        return serviceProvider;
    }

    public void setServiceProvider(DataServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
        this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }
}
```

//and the main action which executed when i click on link from jsp page....
//StartTransAction.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.Random;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;
import test.model.Department;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;


public class StartTransAction extends ActionSupport {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public String execute() throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IOException {      
        Department dept = new Department();
        dept.setDeptid(Long.valueOf(String.valueOf(new Random().nextInt(500))));
        dept.setDeptname("esb");
        System.out.println("before Insert..................Transaction alive? ...." + isActive());
        try {
            updutil.insert(dept);

            System.out.println("After Insert..................Transaction alive? ...." + isActive());
            updutil.select();
            updutil.update(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }finally{
            System.out.println("After Update.................Transaction alive? ....." + isActive());
            updutil.select();
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }
    @Autowired
    fooService updutil;

    public fooService getUpdutil() {
        return new MyUpdateUtil();
    }
    public void setUpdutil(fooService updutil) {
        this.updutil = updutil;
    }
    private DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager;

    public DataSourceTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
        return transactionManager;
    }
    public void setTransactionManager(
            DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        this.transactionManager = transactionManager;
    }   

    public static boolean isActive() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException  {
        ClassLoader contextClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
         Class tsmClass = contextClassLoader.loadClass("org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager");
         Boolean isActive = (Boolean) tsmClass.getMethod("isActualTransactionActive", null).invoke(null, null);
         return isActive;
    }
}
```

Now when i run the program... output is like this:

before Insert.................Transaction alive? .....false 
Inserting..................Transaction alive? ....true
After Insert................Transaction alive? ......false
Dept Info
Dept ID: 1
Dept Name: si
Dept ID: 251
Dept Name: esb
***Dept ID: 293

Dept Name: esb***
Emp Info
Emp ID: 1
Dept ID: 1
Emp Name: s
Updating.................Transaction alive? .....true
java.lang.RuntimeException: simulate Error condition
After Update.................Transaction alive? .....false
Dept Info
Dept ID: 1
Dept Name: si
Dept ID: 251
Dept Name: esb
***Dept ID: 293

Dept Name: esb***
Emp Info
Emp ID: 1
Dept ID: 1
Emp Name: s

---

The bolder part is new record inserted.

**after the runtime exception thrown, i need the inserted record must be rolled back.** But as shown in output, the record get committed even if exception was thrown.
As we can see, the transaction also continued in update() method, too.

Please please help me achieving this. I tried a lot, but not working.
if possible give me working code of above problem....

---

EDIT:
I replaced above code entirely.

Now i have the following files:

//applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
     xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
     xsi:schemaLocation="
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
       <!-- bean id="serviceProvider" class="DataServiceProvider"></bean-->
        <!-- Initialization for data source -->
   <bean id="dataSource" 
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;database=master;integratedSecurity=true;"/>
      <property name="username" value="Jaydeep"/>
      <property name="password" value="Acty#System123"/>

   </bean>

    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name='mapperLocations' value='classpath*:test/xml/*.xml' />
    </bean>

    <bean class='org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer'>
      <property name='basePackage' value='test.dao' />
      <property name="sqlSessionFactoryBeanName" value="sqlSessionFactory" />
    </bean>


    <bean id='sqlSession' class='org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate'>
      <constructor-arg index='0' ref='sqlSessionFactory' />
    </bean>

   <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="nestedTransactionAllowed" value="true" />
        <property name="validateExistingTransaction" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sqlSessionTemplate" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate">
        <constructor-arg index='0' ref='sqlSessionFactory' />
    </bean>

    <bean id="myService" class="service.MyService">
        <property name="sqlSessionTemplate" ref="sqlSessionTemplate" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

//StartTransAction.java

```
package com.acty;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import service.MyService;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class StartTransAction extends ActionSupport {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public String execute(){
        myService.startOperations();
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public static boolean isActive() {
        ClassLoader contextClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
         Class tsmClass = null;
        try {
            tsmClass = contextClassLoader.loadClass("org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         Boolean isActive = null;
        try {
            isActive = (Boolean) tsmClass.getMethod("isActualTransactionActive", null).invoke(null, null);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
                | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException
                | SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         return isActive;
    }

    private MyService myService;

    public void setMyService(MyService myService) {
        this.myService = myService;
    }
}
```

and //MyService.java

```
package service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import test.dao.DepartmentMapper;
import test.dao.EmployeeMapper;
import test.model.Department;
import test.model.Employee;
import test.model.EmployeeExample;

@Service
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class MyService {
    @Autowired
    private SqlSessionTemplate sqlSessionTemplate;

    public void setSqlSessionTemplate(SqlSessionTemplate sqlSessionTemplate) {
        this.sqlSessionTemplate = sqlSessionTemplate;
    }
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void startOperations() {
        DepartmentMapper deptMapper = sqlSessionTemplate.getMapper(DepartmentMapper.class);
        EmployeeMapper empMapper = sqlSessionTemplate.getMapper(EmployeeMapper.class);

        System.out.println("Before Insert Dept" + com.acty.StartTransAction.isActive());

        this.select(deptMapper, empMapper);

        Department dept = new Department();
        //insert new dept
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter dept id ");
        dept.setDeptid(sc.nextLong());
        System.out.println("Enter dept Name ");
        dept.setDeptname(sc.next());

        deptMapper.insert(dept);

        System.out.println("After Insert Dept" + com.acty.StartTransAction.isActive());

        this.select(deptMapper, empMapper);

        this.select(deptMapper, empMapper);
        //now update employee

        EmployeeExample example = new EmployeeExample();
        example.createCriteria().andEmpidEqualTo(1L);

        Employee emp = new Employee();
        emp.setEmpname("jjj");

        try {
        //empMapper.updateByExampleSelective(emp, example);
        empMapper.updateByExampleWithBLOBs(emp, example);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("After Update Emp");

        this.select(deptMapper, empMapper);
    }
    public void select(DepartmentMapper deptMapper, EmployeeMapper empMapper) {
        System.out.println("\nDeptartment\n");
        List<Department> deptList= deptMapper.selectByExampleWithBLOBs(null);
        for(Department de : deptList) {
            System.out.println(" Dept Id : " + de.getDeptid());
            System.out.println(" Dept Name : " + de.getDeptname());
        }
        System.out.println("\nEmployee\n");
        List<Employee> empList= empMapper.selectByExampleWithBLOBs(null);
        for(Employee emp : empList) {
            System.out.println(" Emp Id : " + emp.getEmpid());
            System.out.println(" Emp Name : " + emp.getEmpname());
        }
    }
}
```

//Now im doing the things at service layer.
All DAOs are in other package and i get it from injected by spring.

Then also the trick is not working.
Look the output:
Before Insert Dept  true

Deptartment

 Dept Id : 1
 Dept Name : si
 Dept Id : 2
 Dept Name : esb
 Dept Id : 3

Employee

 Emp Id : 1
 Emp Name : kkkkk
Enter dept id 
4
Enter dept Name 
asdwe
After Insert Depttrue

Deptartment

 Dept Id : 1
 Dept Name : si
 Dept Id : 2
 Dept Name : esb
 Dept Id : 3
 Dept Name : esb
 Dept Id : 4
 Dept Name : asdwe

-- here exception occurs 
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException:

#### Error updating database.  Cause: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Ca

### .....

After Update Emp
Deptartment

 Dept Id : 1
 Dept Name : si
 Dept Id : 2
 Dept Name : esb
 Dept Id : 3
 Dept Name : esb
 Dept Id : 4
 Dept Name : asdwe

...
Look here , department inserted before, is not rolled back here.....
(We can use rollback method for sqlSessionTemplate here, but then what is the use of spring automatic transaction management?? There will no sense by doing this, i believe!)
Whats the problem, i really didnt get...

Plz provide some working solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first transaction, one that has inserted your row is long over and commited when you throw an exception in update. What you probably want to achieve is run entire block in try/catch in `StartTransAction.execute` as a single transaction.

In general it is not recommended to define transactions on dao level - and your `MyUpdateUtil` looks like a dao object with select/insert/update methods. You should manage transactions in service layer.

To begin with, move these lines to a new method in `MyUpdateUtil`:

```
@Transactional
public void insertAndUpdate(Department dept) {
  this.insert(dept);
  this.select();
  this.update(true);
}
```

Then call it from `execute` try/catch block. This will get you a working start point for farther code polishing.

Comment: actually i am new to spring.

I really didnt get how to make service layer. 
As You have told MyUpdateUtil is look like dao, but i already have dao for Department and Employee tables.

You correctly mentioned that i want to achieve run entire block in try/catch as single transaction.

Please give me code snippet describing how to do this at service layer....